# Using java to read/extract data and place in a var

Tags: java

Hay Peeps, I have a question. I am trying to write part of a program. What I need it todo is read a document called marks.txt and then extract the data in the document and place it in variables so that I can calculate the total.

the layout for the document is simply

```
Assessment1 41
Assessment2 41
Assessment3 41
```

When the code is ran the variables that have been declared stay NULL

Here is the code for that part of the program

```
public void readMarks() 
{
    try {
        doc = new File ("marks.txt");

        if(!doc.exists())
        {
            System.out.println ("Marks.txt Does Not Exist");
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(doc);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String Assessment1 = input.next();
            int mark1 = input.nextInt();
            String Assessment2 = input.next();
            int mark2 = input.nextInt();
            String Assessment3 = input.next();
            int mark3 = input.nextInt();
        }  

        input.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File has not been found");
    } 

}
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem ? can't you do `int sum = mart1 + mark2+ mark3;` ?

Comment: Ans what's the question?

Comment: well the question is I cant extract them values the variables simply stay NULL i.e the values that are in the text document are not placed in to the mark 1, mark2 or mark3 variables.

Comment: What do you get in Assessment1/2/3 ? do you have only "Assessment1/2/3" or also the numbers (i.e. Assessment1 41)?

Comment: the text document would be set out like Assessment1 25 Assessment2 63  Assessment3 16 as formatted above

Comment: @Chris The variables can't stay NULL because they are integers. What does happen is that the variables cease to exist after the (unneeded) `while` loop.

Comment: Basically what I am wanting to do is extract both the Assignment name (assignment1) and the int (16) stick those in a variable and then be able to run a calculation method to give the total and then place the results in a new file called AssignmentMarks.txt

Comment: If this is for a homework assignment, you should tag your question with homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to declare variables inside a loop. I have tried this solution and it works flawlessly, if you have any problem probably it is related with marks.txt being in an incorrect location

```
public static void readMarks() 
  {
      String Assessment1 = null, Assessment2 = null, Assessment3 = null;
      int mark1 = 0,mark2 = 0,mark3 = 0;
       try {
       File doc = new File ("marks.txt");
       if(!doc.exists())
       {
        System.out.println ("Marks.txt Does Not Exist");
       }
       Scanner input = new Scanner(doc);
         while (input.hasNext()){
          Assessment1 = input.next();
          mark1 = input.nextInt();
          Assessment2 = input.next();
          mark2 = input.nextInt();
          Assessment3 = input.next();
          mark3 = input.nextInt();

        }  
      input.close();
      System.out.println(Assessment1 + " "+mark1 + Assessment2 +mark2+ " " + Assessment3 +mark3+ " ");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      System.err.println("File has not been found");
    } 

     }
```

If you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Forgot to say, if you want to sum up the marks, declare a variable int sum = 0; out of the loop and include sum += mark1+mark2+mark3;   The loop is wrong since input.hasNext() doesn't ensure that you will have 3 lines to read, what if you only have Assessment 1?

Comment: That sir has done it :D thank you so so much!! Also a Thank toy to everybody else that helped out too :D!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Move the declaration of variables that are storing assignment names and marks outside of the loop.
2. After the loop, sum the variables and write this sum to a file.

You could perhaps use a `Map<String, Integer>` to store the assignments and their marks, putting marks in the `Map` as you iterate through the values returned by the `Scanner`. Then, you would iterate through the `Map` to compute the sum and write it to the file.